# I have a function that returns a PSCustomObject with specific named properties. How can I get these named properties to appear in autocomplete?

Tags: powershell, autocomplete, powershell-core

Here is a simple function that splits a file path into its individual components and assigns them to a handful of properties:

```
function Get-FilePathComponents {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [String[]]
        $Path
    )

    begin {}

    process {

        foreach ($P in $Path) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                ContainingFolder     = Split-Path $P -Parent
                FileBaseName         = Split-Path $P -LeafBase
                FileFullName         = Split-Path $P -Leaf
                FileExtension        = Split-Path $P -Extension
                FullPathNoExtension  = [IO.Path]::Combine((Split-Path $P -Parent),(Split-Path $P -LeafBase))
                CompletePath         = $P
                ParentFolder         = Split-Path (Split-Path $P -Parent) -Parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then use the function like this:

```
$DestFile = "C:\Images\Wallpapers\SomeCoolWallpaper.jpg"
$Components = Get-FilePathComponents $DestFile

$Components.FileFullName     # Outputs SomeCoolWallpaper.jpg
$Components.ContainingFolder # Outputs C:\Images\Wallpapers
```

**What I really need to accomplish** is to somehow enable autocompletion for the returned object and its important properties.

This image below is exactly what I want:

[image: Autocomplete]

I was able to get it to work by defining a custom types.ps1xml file and populating it with `<ScriptProperty>` members that correspond to my parameters:

```
<Types>
<Type>
<Name>VSYSFileOps.Object.FilePathComponents</Name>

<ScriptProperty>
   <Name>ContainingFolder</Name>
   <GetScriptBlock>
      $this.ContainingFolder
   </GetScriptBlock>
</ScriptProperty>

<ScriptProperty>
   <Name>FileBaseName</Name>
   <GetScriptBlock>
      $this.FileBaseName
   </GetScriptBlock>
</ScriptProperty>

<ScriptProperty>
   <Name>FileFullName</Name>
   <GetScriptBlock>
      $this.FileFullName
   </GetScriptBlock>
</ScriptProperty>

... Etc...
```

And then adding `[OutputType('VSYSFileOps.Object.FilePathComponents')]` to the beginning of my function. Surprisingly, while this seems to work, I've been informed by some very knowledgeable people that this is a very bad idea and not what ps1xml files are used for.

I really want to get auto-completion working for this. How can I make this happen?

Any help at all would be extremely welcomed.

*Edit: I am using VSCode with the official PowerShell extension and Powershell Pro Tools.*

### Edit 2 (Working Solution):

---

Many thanks to @AdminOfThings. His advice led me to a great solution.

Here's the final working code:

```
$FilePathComponents = @'
public class FilePathComponents
{
    public string ContainingFolder { get;set; }
    public string FileBaseName { get;set; }
    public string FileFullName { get;set; }
    public string FileExtension { get;set; }
    public string FullPathNoExtension { get;set; }
    public string CompletePath { get;set; }
    public string ParentFolder { get;set; }
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $FilePathComponents -Language CSharp

function Get-FilePathComponents {

    [OutputType("FilePathComponents")]

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [String[]]
        $Path
    )

    begin {}

    process {
        foreach ($P in $Path) {
            $obj = [FilePathComponents]::new()
            $obj.ContainingFolder     = Split-Path $P -Parent
            $obj.FileBaseName         = Split-Path $P -LeafBase
            $obj.FileFullName         = Split-Path $P -Leaf
            $obj.FileExtension        = Split-Path $P -Extension
            $obj.FullPathNoExtension  = [IO.Path]::Combine((Split-Path $P -Parent),(Split-Path $P -LeafBase))
            $obj.CompletePath         = $P
            $obj.ParentFolder         = Split-Path (Split-Path $P -Parent) -Parent
            $obj
        }
    }
}
```

The key was adding `[OutputType("FilePathComponents")]` to the beginning of the function definition. Now, when I use the function outside of the module, Intellisense and TAB completion work like a charm, even without strictly typing the variable name:

[image: Autocompletion]

Comment: Pretty sure this is what custom classes are for, but I'm woefully lacking on knowledge about them. Hopefully somebody with more experience with them can chime in.

Comment: Autocomplete as far as *tab-completion*, intellisense, or both?

Comment: I don’t see a problem with your solution. It also provides you pipeline autocompletion with the use of outputtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go the custom class route, you can add a custom class as a type definition or by loading the class code in a script file/console:

```
# class definition
$class = @'
public class FilePathComponents
{
    public string ContainingFolder { get;set; }
    public string FileBaseName { get;set; }
    public string FileFullName { get;set; }
    public string FileExtension { get;set; }
    public string FullPathNoExtension { get;set; }
    public string CompletePath { get;set; }
    public string ParentFolder { get;set; }
}
'@
# add class to PowerShell session
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $class
# define function
function Get-FilePathComponents {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [String[]]
        $Path
    )

    begin {}

    process {

        foreach ($P in $Path) {
            $obj = [FilePathComponents]::new()
            $obj.ContainingFolder     = Split-Path $P -Parent
            $obj.FileBaseName         = Split-Path $P -LeafBase
            $obj.FileFullName         = Split-Path $P -Leaf
            $obj.FileExtension        = Split-Path $P -Extension
            $obj.FullPathNoExtension  = [IO.Path]::Combine((Split-Path $P -Parent),(Split-Path $P -LeafBase))
            $obj.CompletePath         = $P
            $obj.ParentFolder         = Split-Path (Split-Path $P -Parent) -Parent
            $obj
        }
    }
}

# call your function
$file = Get-FilePathComponents C:\temp\test1\a.csv
# use $file. to auto-populate the properties
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that, I will try it now! Will anything break at all if I include this in a module? The function I'm creating is going to be living within a medium sized module and I've read that you can't export native PowerShell classes without a `using` directive (https://stephanevg.github.io/powershell/class/module/DATA-How-To-Write-powershell-Modules-with-classes/). But since this is an inline C# class it should work just fine, right?

I know a bit of C# so I am definitely comfortable with this solution.

Comment: OK! I got it to work, hurray! Your exact code didn't work but once I added `[OutputType("FilePathComponents")]` before `[CmdletBinding()]` in the function, autocomplete AND tab completion worked like a charm.